# как изменить формат даты в сериализации Json

Tags: json, django, datetime, django-rest-framework

в модели есть поле `date_register = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name = 'Дата регистрации', auto_now_add=True, null=True)`
с помощью django-rest-framework сериализую данные в формат json

```
from rest_framework import serializers 
from .models import Registration 
from django import forms

class RegSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): 
    class Meta: 
        model = Registration 
        fields = ('fio','date_register')
```

во views.py

```
@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated,))
def api_regs(request): 
    if request.method == 'GET': 
        regs = Registration.objects.filter(verification__in=["True"])
        serializer = RegSerializer(regs, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

В итоге в json получаю дату формата "2020-01-23T09:18:45.977201"
а хотелось бы 23.01.2020 18:45
подскажите как сделать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

разобрался, может кому пригодиться в settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {

    'DATETIME_FORMAT': "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S",
}
```